# PnPJs Modern site webpart without SPFx - 404 error

Tags: development, pnpjs

Want to use PnPJs on a content editor webpart added to a modern page. All attempts to use pnp results in a 404. What is seen is that pnp is inserting /SitePages into the API call.

https://{server}/sites/{site}/**SitePages**/_api/search/postquery

There are some solutions for SPFx where context is corrected with some modification to props; however, SPFx is not possible for me due to organization policy/access. Is there a way to set web to the correct url apart from SPFx?

Here is the code attempted:

```
    <div id="main"></div>

    <script>
        pnp.sp.web.select("Title").get()
        .then(function(data){
        document.getElementById("main").innerText=data.Title;
        })   
        .catch(function(data){  
        document.getElementById("main").innerText=data;
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You. need to get the PNPJS library loaded into the page before you can use it.

You’ll need to add the built pnpjs libraries somewhere on your tenant, and the add script tags to your page to reference the libraries,